# openWRT and VDSL speed increase

Tags: openwrt, fiber, vdsl

I have a FTTC tecnology to connect my home to internet.

I use a modem with openWRT as OS (Linux) and I was wondering if there are some parameters to set the speed of my dsl connection to 30 Mbs.

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is limiting the speed, use [QoS](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/uci/qos) (Quality of Service).

If you wish to augment your speed beyond that of your current ISP setting,
contact your ISP for getting a better account or connection media.